# How can i increase mouse scrolling speed on Ubuntu Web Browser?

Tags: mouse, webbrowser-app

The Ubuntu Web Browser scrolling speed (With mouse wheel) is very slow. How can i make it faster?

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is an app called 'imwheel' in the Ubuntu repositories. As there is no native way to change the mouse wheel scroll speed in Ubuntu, you will have to install this to be able to do so.

Sorry, haven't used it myself so I can't comment much, but my understanding is that this is a viable solution to your problem.

However, it looks like slow scrolling has been reported as a bug for the browser:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/oxide/+bug/1555674

You might have to wait for an update that addresses the bug.

Comment: On Firefox and all apps it's ok, but it's on the default browser.